# Simba BigQuery ODBC connection error

Tags: google-bigquery, simba

I have downloaded and install the Simba Big Query ODBC connector.
When I try to configure following the instructions on Simba's website, when I enter the confirmation code at which point the refresh token should populate I get error :-
[Simba]BigQuery Error interacting with REST API: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path ? access rights?)

I get this on both my works laptop and my home PC.
I have also tried the Service Authentication and have selected the key file path and also get the error.

It should be noted I can successfully access Biq Query through other methods using my authorized credentials.

Can anyone help ?

Platform is Windows 64Bit

Regards,
Ian

Comment: You're using the drivers from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/ ?  What platform?

Comment: The platform I am using is Windows 64Bit